# Drawing free resolutions of Stanley-Reisner ideal

Tags: math-mode, tikz-arrows

I want to write LaTex code of the free resolution given in figure below. Is there any one who can assist me?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, ! please see : http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for the arrow in the middle, you should be able to make all the rest in the same fashion.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% needed packages
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}

%% abstract structures
\newsavebox{\smallblockbox}
\newenvironment{smallblockarray}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\smallblockbox}
  \scriptsize$\begin{blockarray}}
 {\end{blockarray}$\end{lrbox}%
  \raisebox{-1ex}[\dimexpr\height-2ex][\dimexpr\depth-1ex]{\usebox{\smallblockbox}}}

\newcommand{\module}[2]{%
  \underset{\mathclap{\begin{smallmatrix}\\#2\end{smallmatrix}}}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\module{S_4}{00011\\11001\\10101\\11110}
\xleftarrow{
  \begin{smallblockarray}{rcccc}
  & abce & abde & acde & abcde \\
  \begin{block}{r[cccc]}
  de & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
  abc & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  ace & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  abcde & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{block}
  \end{smallblockarray}
}
\module{S_4}{11101\\11011\\10111\\11111}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]